# Hostname to fully qualified doman name expansion

Tags: dns, hostname

Is it possible to configure where the system will look for the machine if I enter just a <strike>short domain name</strike> hostname?

I work in a grid environment where the machines are many and spread across multiple domains, but they have unique naming, therefore let say `skirit23` will only be found as `skirit23.ics.muni.cz`

I could configure the full mappings, but that would be a big file (and constantly changing one). Therefore I was thinking if I could configure the system to look into the `ics.muni.cz` then try `ncbr.muni.cz` then try `fav.zcu.cz` etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is usually done by specifying `search` in `/etc/resolv.conf` (see [man 5 resolv.conf](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/resolver.5.html)).

Example (no more than six domains possible):

```
search ics.muni.cz ncbr.muni.cz fav.zcu.cz
```